# how to fix linkedin randomly not showing shared post images?

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

I have a wordpress site with blog2social plugin. when we write a post, that plugin shares the post excerpt and image and link to social media.
Image sizes are 1000x500. I saw that linkedin required 1.91:1 ratio. so I changed my template php and css files to **1000x525**. but the problem is that images randomely are shared correctly even with 1000x500 pixel. but most of the time there is a 1x1 pixel selected for image post. instead of actual post featured image.
also I have let's encrypt ssl on my server so I read in some topics that maybe ssl connection is the issue. but if these are the issues why some of the posts are getting shared with correct images then?
also I tried the link ispector and that selects the correct image from og:image

so picture sizes for all posts are the same. some posts share and view correctly and some show gray block instead of image.

I allowed linkedin IP v4 list in my server firewall. so there may be no connection problem. 
the meta tags are correct . link inspector shows correct OG:image format.

what should I do?

tried link ispector , tried resizing image. tried allowing linkedin cdn ip range.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://---domain---/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/2019-04-05.png">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://---domain---/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/2019-04-05.png">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://---domain---/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/2019-04-05.png">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://---domain---/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/2019-04-05.png">
```

other social media like Facebook, twitter ,Instagram , telegram are showing images without issue. just linked in is randomly failing.

Comment: after lots of trials and no good result , today I could see a log in my apache server error logs :`[access_compat:error] [pid 4863] [client 144.2.2.50:46518] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /public_html/403.shtml`    so I have allowed that ip 144.2.2.0/24 to my server firewall. and working to see why  apache is giving random 403 to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had all in one wordpress firewall and security plugin. and enabled 5g rules in that . I disabled some of the rules. and linkedin images started to work. I think some how this htaccess rules was blocking linkedin crawler . but not the twitter or facebook or insta :

```
#AIOWPS_SIX_G_BLACKLIST_END
#AIOWPS_FIVE_G_BLACKLIST_START
# 5G BLACKLIST/FIREWALL (2013)
# @ http://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/

# 5G:[QUERY STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\"|%22).*(<|>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (javascript:).*(\;) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\\|\.\./|`|='$|=%27$) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\;|'|\"|%22).*(union|select|insert|drop|update|md5|benchmark|or|and|if) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (base64_encode|localhost|mosconfig) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (boot\.ini|echo.*kae|etc/passwd) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (GLOBALS|REQUEST)(=|\[|%) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>

# 5G:[USER AGENTS]
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
# SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ^$ keep_out
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent (binlar|casper|cmsworldmap|comodo|diavol|dotbot|feedfinder|flicky|ia_archiver|jakarta|kmccrew|nutch|planetwork|purebot|pycurl|skygrid|sucker|turnit|vikspider|zmeu) keep_out
<limit GET POST PUT>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=keep_out
</limit>
</IfModule>

# 5G:[REQUEST STRINGS]
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
RedirectMatch 403 (https?|ftp|php)\://
RedirectMatch 403 /(https?|ima|ucp)/
RedirectMatch 403 /(Permanent|Better)$
RedirectMatch 403 (\=\\\'|\=\\%27|/\\\'/?|\)\.css\()$
RedirectMatch 403 (\,|\)\+|/\,/|\{0\}|\(/\(|\.\.\.|\+\+\+|\||\\\"\\\")
RedirectMatch 403 \.(cgi|asp|aspx|cfg|dll|exe|jsp|mdb|sql|ini|rar)$
RedirectMatch 403 /(contac|fpw|install|pingserver|register)\.php$
RedirectMatch 403 (base64|crossdomain|localhost|wwwroot|e107\_)
RedirectMatch 403 (eval\(|\_vti\_|\(null\)|echo.*kae|config\.xml)
RedirectMatch 403 \.well\-known/host\-meta
RedirectMatch 403 /function\.array\-rand
RedirectMatch 403 \)\;\$\(this\)\.html\(
RedirectMatch 403 proc/self/environ
RedirectMatch 403 msnbot\.htm\)\.\_
RedirectMatch 403 /ref\.outcontrol
RedirectMatch 403 com\_cropimage
RedirectMatch 403 indonesia\.htm
RedirectMatch 403 \{\$itemURL\}
RedirectMatch 403 function\(\)
RedirectMatch 403 labels\.rdf
RedirectMatch 403 /playing.php
RedirectMatch 403 muieblackcat
</IfModule>

# 5G:[REQUEST METHOD]
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
#AIOWPS_FIVE_G_BLACKLIST_END
```

so for now I think that 403 was triggered by one of these rules.